# FindLastIndex ArgumentOutOfRangeException when parameter count is less than List.Count

Tags: c#, list

I'm puzzled with a problem regarding C# `List`, the code below throws [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1);
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1);
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); // 15 elements


//              v <--- From 0
l.FindLastIndex(0, 5, v => v != 1);
//                 ^ <--- up to 5 elements
```

As far as I understand the code above, the method will apply the lambda from the element 0 until it reaches 5 elements (element 4), but it throws the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` even if it mustn't according to my understanding of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findlastindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindLastIndex_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Predicate__0__):

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
>
> `startIndex` is outside the range of valid indexes for the `List<T>`.
>
> -or-
>
> `count` is less than 0.
>
> -or-
>
> `startIndex` and `count` do not specify a valid section in the `List<T>`.

The most likely reason is the third one, but `startIndex` is `0` (inside the range) and `count` is far below `l.Count` so the section within the list is 0 to 4, which is valid.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findlastindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindLastIndex_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Predicate__0__) you linked `FindLastIndex(...)` is doing a backward search, meaning it goes to `0`, not to `Count-1`

You are providing a 0 as the starting point and there are in fact less than 5 (your count) elements between 0 and 0.

Changing your to Code something like this will fix it:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1);
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1);
l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1); l.Add(1);

l.FindLastIndex(l.Count - 1, 5, v => v != 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you want (assuming you want to search the first 5 entries backwards)

`l.FindLastIndex(4, 5, v => v != 1);`

as the index is a start of a backwards search

so it will search from index 4 for 5 counts back to index 0